# Sign Microsoft Windows executable with a key valid by the chain model but not the shell model

Tags: windows, certificate, exe, code-signing, signtool

I have a digital key which is valid until 2019. However the certifing key and the root certificate have been valid until March 2017 only. Hence my key is not valid anymore under the shell modell (where the outer keys must be valid at least as long the inner one is valid). Microsoft Windows does not except my key as valid anymore although the key itself is valid:

[image]

Moreover I am unable to use it with `signtool` to sign an executable:

[image]

Before March 2017 I was able to use the key for code signing.

Is there a way to use the key with signtool even if the root certificate is not valid anymore? Is there any other tool with which I can sign Microsoft Windows executables? Does [osslsigncode](https://sourceforge.net/projects/osslsigncode/) allow for such certificates?

Comment: If the root cert is not valid, also the key is not longer valid

Comment: @Jens This is true under the so called shell model. However, the German law sets the chain modell. Under this model the key is valid even if the root cert is not valid anymore. I had to learn this from the support of my card provider and it is the reason why I am looking for alternative solutions.